# Разместить текст по правой стороне картинки

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/6rLV7/

```html
<div style="display: inline-block; max-width: 75px;">
  <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 2;">
    <div style="text-align: right !important">123</div>
  </div>
  <img style="position: relative" src="http://cs10758.vk.me/u156650173/e_59774215.jpg">
</div>
```

Как разместить текст по правой стороне картинки? На данный момент по левой, text-align: right отказывается это делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6rLV7/1/

```html
<div style="display: inline-block; max-width: 75px;">
    <img style="float: left;" src="http://cs10758.vk.me/u156650173/e_59774215.jpg" />
    <div>123</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Немного изменил вашу разметку. [Вот результат](http://jsfiddle.net/6rLV7/2/).

```html
<div style="display: inline-block; max-width: 75px; position: relative">
    <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 0; right: 0;">
        123
    </div>
    <img src="http://cs10758.vk.me/u156650173/e_59774215.jpg" />
</div>
```